# Leverage point in a dataset

Tags: statistics

Given a data set $(x_1, ... , x_n)$, is there a condition which makes a point $x_i$ leverage? That is, how can we point ( except for just considering it 'too far from the other points and probably being an error estimate' ) ? Is there an algorithm for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you are talking about linear regression. There is a rule-of-thumb measure for leverage. It is based on the diagonal values of the hat matrix $H=X(X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ Point i is considered leverage point if $h_{ii} > 2 \frac{k}{N}$, where k is the number of parameters including the intercept and N is the number of observations. If the data set is small you might want to use 3 instead of 2. See John Fox An R Companion to Applied Regression

Comment: Yes, I was talking about this. Thank you!